# Find word (not containing substrings) in comma separated string

Tags: asp.net, linq, search, csv, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a linq query where i do something liike this:

```
viewModel.REGISTRATIONGRPS = (From a In db.TABLEA
    Select New SubViewModel With {
    .SOMEVALUE1 = a.SOMEVALUE1,
    ...
    ...
    .SOMEVALUE2 = If(commaseparatedstring.Contains(a.SOMEVALUE1), True, False)
    }).ToList()
```

Now my Problem is that this does'n search for words but for substrings so for example:

commaseparatedstring = "EWM,KI,KP"
SOMEVALUE1 = "EW"

It returns true because it's contained in EWM?

What i would need is to find words (not containing substrings) in the comma separated string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Regular Expressions**

```
Regex.IsMatch(commaseparatedstring, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(a.SOMEVALUE1) + @"\b")
```

The `\b` parts are called "[word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)" and tell the regex engine that you are looking for a "full word". The `Regex.Escape(...)` ensures that the regex engine will not try to interpret "special characters" in the text you are trying to match. For example, if you are trying to match `"one+two"`, the `Regex.Escape` method will return `"one\+two"`.

Also, be sure to include the System.Text.RegularExpressions at the top of your code file.

See [Regex.IsMatch Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

**Option 2: Split the String**

You could also try splitting the string which would be a bit simpler, though probably less efficient.

```
commaseparatedstring.Split(new Char[] { ',' }).Contains( a.SOMEVALUE1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation but I'm getting a 'LINQ to Entities' System.NotSupportedException on both options?

Comment: Ok I ended up doing the split outside the query `Dim fn As New List(Of String)(dataObject.REGISTRATIONGRP.Split(","c))` and inside then `If(fn.Contains(benutzergrp.BENUTZERGRP_KUERZEL), True, False)` which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

what about:
- separating the commaseparatedstring by comma 
- calling equals() on each substring instead of contains() on whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

.SOMEVALUE2 = If(commaseparatedstring.Split(',').Contains(a.SOMEVALUE1), True, False)